# Grouping controllers by custom Attribute in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to implement 'route grouping' of my controllers by custom attribute, similar like ApiVersioning.

What I would like to have on my controllers:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/g{group:apiGroup}/v{version:apiVersion}/Authorization")]
public class AuthorizationController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ApiGroup("NAS")] /// <--- MY GROUPING
    [Route("VerifyCredentials")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(ContactPerson))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> VerifyCredentials(Credentials credentials)
    {....}
```

So route to this Api call would be localhost/Api/NAS/V1/Authorization

I was succesful with the versioning using the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning package.

My custom Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ApiGroupAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string GroupName { get; private set; }

    public ApiGroupAttribute(string groupName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("groupName");
        }
        GroupName = groupName;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Ive tried to achieve this with routeConstraint but learned it does not work like that. How do you achieve this 'Dynamic' routing?

Edit:
So after some digging inside the code, I found out I have to imlement my own DirectRouteProvider, any help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems I just solved it..
Heres my code:

```
public class CentralizedRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override IReadOnlyList<RouteEntry> GetActionDirectRoutes(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory> factories, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver)
    {
        var result = base.GetActionDirectRoutes(actionDescriptor, factories, constraintResolver).ToList();
        var list = new List<RouteEntry>();

        foreach (var route in result.Where(r => r.Route.RouteTemplate.Contains("[ApiGroup]")))
        {
            var attribute = ((ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor)actionDescriptor).GetCustomAttributes<ApiGroupAttribute>().First();

            var newTemplate = route.Route.RouteTemplate.Replace("[ApiGroup]", attribute.GroupName);

            if (!result.Any(r => r.Route.RouteTemplate == newTemplate))
            {
                var entry = new RouteEntry(null, new HttpRoute(newTemplate,
                    new HttpRouteValueDictionary(route.Route.Defaults),
                    new HttpRouteValueDictionary(route.Route.Constraints),
                    new HttpRouteValueDictionary(route.Route.DataTokens)));
                list.Add(entry);
            }
        }

        return list.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```